# Show ProgressBar over Dialog Fragment

Tags: android, kotlin, progress-bar, android-alertdialog, android-dialogfragment

I have a class that extends `DialogFragment` and inside it I want to show a full screen loader. The problem is that the `ProgressBar` is shown behind the `DialogFragment`, not over it, how I want.

For showing `ProgressBar` I use this [library](https://github.com/ybq/Android-SpinKit)  and I just put the `SpinKitView` inside the `DialogFragment` layout

.

[image]

Comment: Can you share your DialogFragment code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know this is a bit late but figured I'd put an answer here so that it may help future people that are stuck. @ghita if you could mark this as what solved your issue?

```
 <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

<Button android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="143dp"
    android:layout_height="168dp"
    android:text="Button"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.432" />

<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progressBar"
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyle"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:elevation="27dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/button"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/button"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/button"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can either use frameLayout with 2 views in it(that way 1 view is above another) or constraint layout,  here is an example for using constraint layout :

```
   <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="143dp"
        android:layout_height="168dp"
        android:text="Button"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.432" />

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/button"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/button"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/button"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button"
        />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: so, to have the `progressBar` inside my DialogFragment layout? That's what I have done, but it doesn't show it.  Also I use `SpinKitView` , but it extends Progressbar

Comment: Yes, you need to have `progressBar` inside your dialog. if you have done this and you are not seeing your progressBar than just go to your XML and swap your 2 views in the positions(so that your progress bar will now be above your layout)

Comment: You could also use the elevation attribute, by default dialogs are at 24dp elevation, so set your progress loading bars elevation at something like 26 through 30. Here is a link showing examples https://material.io/design/environment/elevation.html#elevation-in-material-design

Comment: @Vahalaru sure dialogs got elevation but remember that both of the views are inside the same layout(of the dialog), but good tip about the elevation - nice way of thinking

Comment: True forgot about that. This method would take a but of effort cuz youd have to set a custom elevation for these views to get it right. But I've done crazier things when I was desperate to make something work.

Comment: Just remember that when something is working it is not always smart

Comment: Yes, it worked with the elevation thing, thank @Vahalaru !

Comment: @Tamir Abutbul would you rather have 60 - 80 percent of something done or 0 percent done? If it works it works. You can always improve on it later.  But ain't nobody got time for useless hours,  days, or weeks  on some weird issue.... which ends up getting you side tracked,  then you start looking sy this and that.  Meanwhile someone else got the job done 6 months ago. *mic drop*

Comment: @ghita your welcome sir,  if you didn't read my last comment,  this is something that will need to be optimized